# SyntaxError with nested quotes in Python

Tags: python, twitter, xauth

I am using a Twitter XAuth Python library and I keep getting an Invaild Syntax Error. I am still learning python but I couldn't find  the solution when I was looking. Here is the code giving the error. Any help would be great.

```
req = urllib2.Request(post_url, data = urllib.urlencode(params))
req.add_data(urllib.urlencode({'status' : message}))
req.add_header('Authorization', 'OAuth %s' % ', '.join(
  ['%s='%s'' % (x, urllib.quote(params[x], '')) for x in params]))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You have two random parentheses at the end of the line, and</strike> you should use double quotes around your string—Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting should make that clear. Next time, include the full stack trace.

**EDIT:** with the updated question, the parentheses are no longer an issue.

```
req.add_header('Authorization', 'OAuth %s' % ', '.join(
    ["%s='%s'" % (x, urllib.quote(params[x], '')) for x in params]))
```

See how everything that's part of the string is red in SO's syntax highlighting?

Comment: Will do! 6 minutes than i can!